# How do I view animation without rendering?

Tags: rendering, animation

Is there a way to preview the entire clip? The timeline does have another mode where it allows you to see in seconds, but it doesn't help much. It's kind of annoying to wait for it to render everything just to check if things are moving too fast or slow. I just want to know if the flow of movement is going smoothly because when you hit the play button everything moves so slow it's hard to tell.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the display mode you want, like *Solid*, then go into camera view and *View > Viewport Render Animation*:

[image]

It will export the movie or images into the folder and in the dimensions set in the *Output* panel. To watch the result go into *Render > View Animation*:

[image]

As pointed out by Gordon Brinkmann: *Another advantage of this method is you can render any view you like from angles other than the camera view*.

Comment: Oh man, be slower!!! Why do I even start answering? 

Comment: If I'm awake don't even try!!

Comment: *lol* I was just about to finish my answer by adding, another advantage of this method is you can render any view you like from angles other than the camera view (you don't even need any camera for the viewport render) if this helps to see certain parts of the animation better.

Comment: Sure I'm going to add that, thanks

Comment: You two are funny, but I agree. It is always a race against time when moonboots is awake. :D

Comment: I leave you all the questions about GeoNodes (and Python things)   ^^

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would usually change the render engine to *Workbench*, and then render the animation out. I think, you can output file format as  *FFmpeg* Video in *MPEG-4* Container. This way, You have a video output to see all the movement without any lag.